# NSUserNotification использование deliveryRepeatInterval

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

Как правильно задавать этот интервал?
Мне нужно чтобы моя нотификация повторялась каждую неделю. Но для начала я решил попробовать выводить её каждую минуту. В документации написано что нужно всего-лишь у проперти deliveryRepeatInterval поставить нужное значение (сам проперти по умолчанию nil). Если я создаю свою DateComponent с текущей датой (да и с любой), то сообщения начинают пушится чуть ли не каждую милисекунду!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что при создании компонента даты я указывал лишние компоненты. почему именно была ошибка я так и не понял, но суть такова, что лишнее лучше не указывать